# Vapor Web Framework: error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.11.sdk'

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, vapor

When trying to build Vapor 0.13 (and likely other versions) w/ Swift 3 and Xcode

**Environment**

```
Vapor: 0.13
Swift: 3
Snapshot: DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-06-20-A
Xcode: 8
```

The following error is often the first result:

> error: Swift does not support the SDK 'MacOSX10.11.sdk'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

NOTE: This is a Q&A Question that is being answered by the author.

This is an issue of having Xcode 7 already installed, and the latest snapshot being unable to run properly.

Execute the following steps

1. Completely open Xcode 8 and install additional components as prompted
2. Make sure you've downloaded `DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-06-20-A` [here](https://swift.org/download/#snapshots)
3. Run the following command

   ```
   sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/
   ```

   or go to Xcode preferences, then to the Locations tab and setting the "Command Line Tools" popup to Xcode 8.0.

   This will tell your system to use the Xcode-beta tools which support latest Swift

   > Note: In above example, Xcode-beta is expected to be the name of your beta. If you change the names to something like Xcode-beta2, replace above. In occasional situations, users have had to do -s /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer
4. Return to your project and Verify that your project specifies Vapor `0.13`, it will look like this:

   ```
   .Package(url: "https://github.com/qutheory/vapor.git", majorVersion: 0, minor: 13),
   ```
5. Build your Xcode project

   ```
   swift package generate-xcodeproj
   ```
6. Completely quit Xcode 7 if it is running
7. Open Xcode project with `open *.xcodeproj`
8. Verify the project was opened with `Xcode 8`
9. Select toolchain `Xcode > Toolchains > DEVELOPMENT-SNAPSHOT-06-20-A`
10. Run project

If you have any more questions, checkout the [#help](http://slack.qutheory.io) channel in [our slack](http://slack.qutheory.io).

Comment: Step 3 in the first block can also be performed in Xcode preferences, by going to the Locations tab and setting the "Command Line Tools" popup to Xcode 8.0.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Thanks, I added that to the answer.